# How to get a custom value using Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a $_SESSION array variable with post ids. Inside foreach loop, I would like to get the posts titles of these ids. Thus so far I have something like this:

```
sport_title = '';
foreach($_SESSION['sports_post_id'] as $sports_id {
    $sport_title = get_the_title($sport_id);
    $sports_titles .= $sport_title . "<br />";
}
```

Now, my problem is that I do not know how to pass it in a custom variable in Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension plugin.

I have inside my form this field (inside CF7):

```
[dynamichidden dynamic_sports readonly default:shortcode_attr]
```

and inside my custom page template php file:

```
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="3561" "CF7_get_custom_field dynamic_sports=\'$sports_titles\'" title="Availability Form EN"]');
```

Thus, I would like to send these post titles in email.. How can I make it work? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I figure it out how to do it! If anyone wants more explanation:

Inside Contact Form 7 - Form tab, I have insert this code:

```
[dynamichidden dynamic_sports "CF7_GET key='sports_post_id'"]
```

where **key** is a standard word (could not change it).

Inside Email tab, you should have this code:

```
Sports: [dynamic_sports]
```

Now, inside my Custom template PHP file, I have this shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="3561" title="Availability Form EN"]');
```

I also have a form with a hidden input type, with a name sports_post_id and value the id of the current post:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_the_title( get_the_ID() ); ?>" name="sports_post_id" id="sports_post_id" />
```

**EDITED**

Another solution via plugin that extends the CF7, would be the following:

1. Install **[Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/)**
2. Copy and paste the form-tag code below and then add it inside the form code block

   ```
   [dynamichidden page-title "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]
   ```

The above code will add a hidden text input to the form which will pre-populate the page title. This is good to use when you are using the same contact form on multiple pages so you know where the user has submitted the form from. Alternatively, you can display the page URL or slug using one of the below shortcodes instead:

```
[dynamichidden page-url "CF7_bloginfo show='url'"]
[dynamichidden page-slug "CF7_bloginfo show='url'"]
```

**Displaying the Hidden Dynamic Content Tag Variable in Contact Form 7**

Finally, display the hidden dynamic content tag variable in Contact Form 7 form. While you are on the CF7 settings page, click on the "**Email**" tab and insert this:

```
[page-title]
```

If you are using the URL or Slug fields, you these instead:

```
[page-url]
[page-slug]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CF7 Form configuration > Email Tab, you only have to add the desired field between hooks `[...]`

```
[dynamic_sports]
```

This will print the dynamic field value in your email.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.. This is exactly what I have in Email tab.. Should I have something in Form tab? Moreover, my shortcode is correct? CF7_get_custom_field is nessesary.. or should I erase it? dynamic_sports=\'$sports_titles\'" leave it as is?