# Create hidden input and populate it with uid in CF7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to send unique id along with form data so its possible to retrieve it and save it under this ID in CRM and other systems - once the form is submitted I retrieve the data and use curl to send it to CRM

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'on_cf7_submit' );

function on_cf7_submit( $contact_form ){
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();  
    $id = $submission->get_posted_data('lead-id'); <---- here is the problem
    $fullName = $submission->get_posted_data('your-name');  
    $email = $submission->get_posted_data('your-email');
    $phone = $submission->get_posted_data('your-phone');
    ........
```

Tried this snippet, but wasn't even able to create the hidden input in the html

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'init_form' );

function init_form( $tag ) {
    $id = uniqid(rand());
    return "<input type='hidden' name='lead-id' value='$id' />";
}
```

Comment: try echoing instead of returning?

Comment: This is part of Contact form 7 already. https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/#user-related

Comment: @CKMacLeod echoing actually creates the element but the value isn't submitted with the form, probably because the element is not in the form div

Comment: @HowardE users are not logged in, so I cant use that build in feature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a custom value using Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719006/how-to-get-a-custom-value-using-contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension)

Comment: @Moishy As you see I'm not very familiar with wordpress, but I don't see any connection between my problem and that answer

Comment: It will allow you to add dynamic content to the form